# LIRC in 14.04 (needed for XBMC)

Tags: lirc

I just installed 14.04 Trusty Tahr (Beta).

When running XBMC (Gotham nightly build) on in and using my LIRC remote control I noticed that only the arrow keys and Volume keys (including mute) work. All the other keys don't.

It's a standard MCE remote control, and the receiver is connected by USB. I got them both in a package and the remote control was manufactured by Linksys and the receiver by HP (or at least so it's written on them).

I tried testing the configuration by running `gnome-lirc-properties` but it won't start (missing module `glade`, and still missing it after I installed glade).

Then I tried testing for inputs by running `irw` but it also won't run because it is looking for configuration files or stream files that aren't there. The same goes for running `lircd`, which I find weird as I saw the remote is partially working, meaning there is something there that reads its inputs.

What else do I need to check and/or how can I configure the default IR support that came out of the box?

Comment: Try installing `libglade2-0` and `libglade2-0-dev`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try reconfiguring `lirc` with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lirc` and reset the controller type through that, and also check out the [XBMC guide for `lirc` configurations](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=HOW-TO%3aSetup_an_MCE_remote_control_in_Linux).